# how to embed html to html file using Python

Tags: python, html, embed, writetofile

file.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <title>Hey</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class='element'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Python code:

```
html = '<div id="child">Hello</div>
```

I want to embed the html in the Python code into the html file inside the div with class "element". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do such changes using BeautifulSoup as below. You can read more about [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

with open('<file_path>') as f: 
   soup = Soup(f)

elementDiv = soup.find('div', {"class": "element"}) # find div with class name as element
newDiv = soup.new_tag('div') # adds a new tag
newDiv['id'] = "child"
newDiv.string = "Hello"
elementDiv.append(newDiv) # appends the newDiv within the elementDiv

print(soup)
```

Comment: What if the html file is big? Can I create Soup object given a file path ?

Comment: @Petar It is possible. I have updated the answer now where I am reading from the HTML file

Comment: Thank you! Good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could either work with HTML as with regular XML using [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) or better use de-facto standard templating engine Jinja2 and its [`include`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#include) directive.